# can't import circle in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

```
from circle import Circle

circles = [ Circle(0, 0, 4), Circle(4, 2, 1) ]

for circle in circles:
    print("         Info:", circle)
    print("         Area: {:.2f}".format(circle.area()))
    print("Circumference: {:.2f}".format(circle.circumference()))
    print()

if circles[0] == circles[1]:
    print("Circles are equal.\n")
else:
    print("Circles are not equal.\n")
```

I have run this code on Spyder. But error shows the console file. Please give me a solution for this. I'm new user of Spyder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1q0J.jpg)

Comment: circle is a module you wrote yourself I assume? Or some smaller project?
This is most likely due to other imports or cross imports that the cicle module has not been executed to the end. How does it roughly look like?

Comment: bad request... please format your code, and do not post pictures of code or errors...

Comment: Did you call your own script `circle.py`? In that case Python tries to import your script. Rename it. And ... next time please add the error message as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @Matthias has nailed it.  Your error traceback shows that you named your own file `circle.py`.  Don't do that.  Python will try to import your own file again, leading to a loop.